# Angular2 Use Components initialized class in HTML

Tags: html, function, angular

I was wondering if the following was possible. Can I use a component's initialized classes in the HTML to call a function that isn't in the component? For example:

```
@Component
...
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
   simpleHandler:SimpleHandler = new SimpleHandler();
...
```

Then in the HTML call it like so?

```
<div>
{{simpleHandler.isValid()}}
</div>
```

Or can it only call functions and properties on the components themselves?

When I try to do this, it gives this error:

```
TypeError: self.parentView.parentView.context.simpleHandler.isValid is not a function
```

Comment: you should be able to do it. i have cases like that. check that simpleHandler.isValid function exist

Comment: Weird... it does work. Thank you. I tested something smaller and found out where my problem is at. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. For example, this pattern is used by ng2-file-upload

```
@Component({
  selector: 'simple-demo',
  templateUrl: './simple-demo.html'
 })
 export class SimpleDemoComponent {
   public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
   ...
 }
```

and in html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
    (click)="item.upload()" [disabled]="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
</button>
```